# Changing of GridView while adding to RelativeLayout

Tags: android, xml, gridview

I have such an xml file:

**UPD**

```
     <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context=".ProgramsFragment"
android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark">

        <!-- TODO: Update blank fragment layout -->


        <ScrollView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <GridView
                    android:id="@+id/gridView"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:numColumns="auto_fit"
                    android:columnWidth="200dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"/>

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                    android:text="@string/your_articles"
                    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:textStyle="bold"/>
            </LinearLayout>
        </ScrollView>
    </FrameLayout>
```

My aim was to make a scrollable layout, which contains GridView and TextView. TextView shoulde me below the GridView. When I run my program GridView size become small and I don't know why. Probably there's nothing in textview what can change GridView size in a such way (as I think). But maybe I am wrong, as when I delete TextView, RelativeLayout and ScrollView everything works correctly. What's the matter? Here's a screen of my problem:

[image]

**UPD2**

I add to GridView by this way:

```
private final String[] programs = {"Slim body for a four weeks", "Exercises for woman at home", "Effective exercises for biceps at home",
        "Program of effective trainings twice a week", "Training on a horizontal bar for increasing muscle mass",
        "Fitness program for woman: trainings at home at in gym"};
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,programs);
    GridView gridView = view.findViewById(R.id.gridView);
    gridView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

**UPD3**

I added line `android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"` to this file and the result is on screen [image]. As I understand, whole fragment takes this part of layout. But why? There are some almost same fragments and the take all the place.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `linearlayout` instead of `relativelayout`. Additionally, you can use nestedscrollview.

Comment: What or how you put something into the gridview?

Comment: What are you meaning by gridview size become small? How it looks like?

Comment: Before adding the linearlayout it was on the full screen and now it's on the quarter and even less